# Find NaN and Added to the new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to remove duplicates from an array however, when I have NaN inside and array it does not work. How can I detect NaN and push it only once to a new array

I have tried this code and it works well with other scenarions but not with NaN

```
removeDupReduce([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4]) // Works Fine
removeDupReduce([NaN, 2, NaN, 3, 1, NaN]) // It returns ['NaN', 2, 3, 1] Instead I want it to return [NaN, 2, 3, 1] I know I have converted into string using toString. but dont though of other ideas.

function removeDupReduce(list) {
    return [...list].reduce((acc,curr)=>{

        if(acc.indexOf(curr) === -1){
            if(isNaN(curr)){
                curr = curr.toString()
                if(acc.indexOf(curr) === -1)
                acc.push(curr)
            }
            else{
            var a = acc.indexOf(curr)
            acc.push(curr)
            }
        }
        return acc
    },[])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array.findIndex` to search for NaN, like so:

```js
function removeDupReduce(list) {
    return [...list].reduce((acc,curr)=>{

        if(acc.indexOf(curr) === -1){
            if(isNaN(curr)){
                if(acc.findIndex(Number.isNaN) === -1)
                acc.push(curr)
            }
            else{
            var a = acc.indexOf(curr)
            acc.push(curr)
            }
        }
        return acc
    },[])
}
console.log("removeDupReduce([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4])")
console.log(removeDupReduce([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4]))
console.log("removeDupReduce([NaN, 2, NaN, 3, 1, NaN])")
console.log(removeDupReduce([NaN, 2, NaN, 3, 1, NaN]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for NaN using `acc.find(a => a !== a)` or `acc.find(a => isNaN(a))` both works.

```
removeDupReduce([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4]) // Works Fine
removeDupReduce([NaN, 2, NaN, 3, 1, NaN]) // It returns ['NaN', 2, 3, 1] Instead I want it to return [NaN, 2, 3, 1] I know I have converted into string using toString. but dont though of other ideas.

function removeDupReduce(list) {
    return [...list].reduce((acc,curr)=>{

        if(acc.indexOf(curr) === -1){
            if(isNaN(curr)){
                if(acc.find(a => a !== a))
                acc.push(curr)
            }
            else{
            var a = acc.indexOf(curr)
            acc.push(curr)
            }
        }
        return acc
    },[])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NaN` is not equal to `NaN`. It may be counter intuitive, but it it what it is.

`indexOf` will check items one by one to see if they equal with your value, but because `NaN != NaN` so it will always return -1.

To verify this just run:

```
[NaN].indexOf(NaN) // this will return -1
```

If you want to check if an array contains `NaN` use find and use `isNaN`.

```
if (acc.find(item => isNaN(item)) // we have NaN in the array.
```

You need to update your if condition to reflect this.

```
if(acc.indexOf(curr) === -1 && (!isNaN(curr) || !acc.find(item => isNaN(item))) {
 acc.push(curr)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because your if statement isn't correct. You can check is `Boolean(curr)` true or not, because `Boolean(NaN)` gives you false.
When you specify just the name of the variable `curr` inside the condition, it is set to `Boolean(curr)` and checks `true` or `false` accordingly. Also in your code, you duplicate the condition if `acc.indexOf()`. Tryout my solution

```js
console.log(removeDupReduce([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4]))
console.log(removeDupReduce([NaN, 2, NaN, 3, 1, NaN]))
function removeDupReduce(list) {
    return [...list].reduce((acc,curr)=> curr && acc.indexOf(curr) === -1 ? [...acc, curr] : acc, [])
}
```